# Apache Phoenix on Spark - Unable to insert to Phoenix HBase Tables/Need suggestion for Best practice

Tags: apache-spark, apache-phoenix

I have a table with the structure below.

trans_count

```
start_time,           end_time,                count

00:00:01              00:00:10                 1000

00:00:11              00:00:20                 800
```

Spark listens for events from Kafka and does a grouping for 10 seconds and will have to insert to Phoenix hbase table.

After 10 seconds, i have to first check if the start_time,end_time combination is in the table. If it is there, we have to take the existing count and add the new count and upsert it again.

```
UPSERT INTO trans_count(start_time, end_time, count) SELECT start_time, end_time, count? FROM trans_count WHERE start_time = ? AND end_time = ?
```

If no rows upserted in the above statement, then simply upsert the data.

In Apache Storm, i was able to create a Phoenix Connection object in the configure method and was able to use the same connection once every 10 seconds to UPSERT.

In Spark, I could not create a connection object and use the same object for every Object in the RDD.
My output from spark will be a JavaDStream> where start_time, end_time, count are all keys in the Map.

I end up creating a connection object for every iteration of RDD, which i feel is not the right way. I have read that Phoenix connections are light weight but creating a connection object for every RDD seems to be not the right way.

I read some blogs about related stuff, but could not getting this going. Kindly help.

NOTE : The appliation is built in JAVA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Instead of creating a connection per objectin RDD, Create a connection per partition in the RDD and use that for all the objects.